# How to test entries in a DataFrame in sparkR

Tags: r, sparkr

I have a DataFrame in sparkR called `pgz`. It contains `user_id` and `time`. For a fixed user_id `k` I get

```
y <- filter(pgz, pgz$user_id == k)
```

When I type `head(y)` and I can see some of the times for user_id `k`. "2005-02-04" , "2005-06-06".. They are all sorted so they increase. 
For this `user_id` I want to test if he has `times` larger than a fixed time I set to

```
fixtime <- "2010-01-01"
```

I would like to save all user_id's that has times larger than fixtime.
How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get started, let's create some example data to test

```
set.seed(1)
dd = data.frame(id = base::sample(1:3, 4,TRUE), 
                times = base::sample(c("2005-02-04" , "2005-06-06", "2007-02-04" , "2006-06-06"), 
                                     12, TRUE))
dd$times = as.Date(dd$times)
NROW(dd[dd$id==1 & dd$times > as.Date("2006-01-01"),])
```

For this data set, we should get the answer 2.

Create Spark data frame

```
dd_sp = createDataFrame(sqlContext, dd)
```

and then filter

```
dd_sp_k = filter(dd_sp, dd_sp$id== 1 & 
             dd_sp$times > as.Date("2006-01-01"))
```

Then we can use `summarise` to get the length of the data frame

```
## This seems a bit clunky, bit it works.
summarize(dd_sp_k, count = n(dd_sp_k$times)) %>%
  head
```

which gives 2.